# How do I fix the error "Cannot POST /Index.html" when I am trying to make a calculator with javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Okay, I am following along with a web development course on Udemy where in one of the modules, we had to make a simple javascript, node/express/body-parser and HTML calculator. I did it exactly as she did it but somehow, I got an error when I submitted the numbers on the calculator saying "*Cannot POST /index.html*" here is my code

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);

    res.send("Thanks for Posting that! ");
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server Started on Port 3000");
});
```

My **HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="index.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="First Number">
        <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>;
</body>

</html>
```

I already installed body-parser and express using hyper-terminal. And I'm using VS-Code, I just want it to say Thanks for posting that.

Comment: It seems you've made two endpoints, one GET, one POST, on the same URL? Is this intentional?

Comment: yes it is intentional.

Comment: There is no route for `form action="index.html"`

Comment: is it wrong that i made two endpoints??

Comment: I don't know if it's wrong, I just wanted to check if you did it intentionally. Also, you don't seem to be serving static files?

Comment: I just want this code to say when I submit two numbers, Thanks for Posting that as that is my objective right now

Comment: should i be serving static files because I'm completely a noob at this.

Comment: You either need a route `app.post('/index.html'` or you have to change the action to something like `form action="/"`. Maybe you can omit it.

Comment: well how can i change the action??

Comment: I did it as my instructor did it

Comment: Your code as posted can't work. Maybe you're missing something important your instructor did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the action of your form to http://127.0.0.1:3000/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="First Number">
        <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>;
</body>

</html>
```

Express is listening the port 3000, so you your action have to send the data to this port

Comment: I suspect that the `action` could be removed completely. Browsers that encounter a form with no action will just "post to self", which is what is happening here. (It is not ideal to hardwire things like protocol, address, and port, since these things can change).